# Regex - match specific characters after a given pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match uppercase characters (but could be something else) that appear in a string after the first comma.

I have list of names where last names and first names are separated by a comma.

```
Stevenson, Barry J. F.
Smith, Julia
```

And I want to match something like that

```
B J F
J
```

I tried to use lookbehind expression like `(?<=, )[A-Z]`, but it match only the first character following the comma. Can somebody help?

Comment: What means `but could be something else`? Your question is pretty vague

Comment: I just mean that it could be used to match something else. But my question is precisely in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this, as far as I know, with regular expressions will require `\G` (so some regex engines will not be able to execute this expression):

```
/(?:,|\G(?!^))[^A-Z]*\K[A-Z]/g
```

[***Demo.***](https://regex101.com/r/vNea5a/3)

---

The use of `\G` is crucial because it lets us begin matching from the end of our last match (or the beginning of the string, which is why `(?!^)` is necessary) -- everything after the comma.

I also use `\K` to "reset" the match so you don't need to use a capturing group; but, you could easily replace the end with `[^A-Z]*([A-Z])` and access the capture group.

Finally, you could use a lazy dot-match-all (`.*?`) instead of `[^A-Z]*`; but, I prefer to be more specific when possible.

---

Here's an expanded explanation:

```
(?:      (?# Start non-capturing group for alternation)
  ,      (?# Match a comma)
 |       (?# OR)
  \G     (?# Match the end of the last match)
  (?!^)  (?# Dont match the beginning)
)        (?# End non-capturing group)
[^A-Z]*  (?# Match 0+ non-capital letters)
\K       (?# Reset the match for clarity)
[A-Z]    (?# Match capital letter)
```

Comment: Just a little side note - you should place the lookahead behind `\G`, so it is only evaluated when needed.

Comment: @SebastianProske do you mean something other then `(?!^)\G`? If so, I'd appreciate an example since I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `\G(?!^)`, so basically the other way around.

Comment: @Sam, this answer doesn't work for what OP wants. Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vNea5a/2) and you will see that it's matching the `S` of `Smith`

Comment: @FedericoPiazza This could be worked around by adding `\n` to the negated character class, however I think it is more likely, that those strings are evaluated line by line.

Comment: Yes they are evaluated line by line. Thank you very much, this is working perfectly!

Comment: @SebastianProske thank you, I guess I had been doing that backwards all along! Saved on ~20% of the steps in my demo.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to remove the comma and it will match what you want:

```
(?<= )[A-Z]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX1uJK/1)**

[image]